# TensorFlow 2.0 'tf.function' annotated - ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am using TensorFlow 2.0 and Python 3.7.5 for MNIST dataset using 300-100-10 dense fully connected feed forward neural network for classification using *tf.function* decorated function using *GradientTape*. The code I have is as follows:

```
def nn_model():
    """
    Function to create LeNet 300-100-10
    model for MNIST classification
    """

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(l.InputLayer(input_shape=(784, )))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(units = 300, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform()))

    # model.add(l.Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(units = 100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.GlorotUniform()))

    # model.add(l.Dropout(0.1))

    model.add(Dense(units = num_classes, activation='softmax'))

    return model


# Create training and testing datasets-
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))


train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size = 20000, reshuffle_each_iteration = True).batch(batch_size = batch_size, drop_remainder = False)

test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size, drop_remainder=False)

# Choose an optimizer and loss function for training-
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001)

# Select metrics to measure the error & accuracy of model.
# These metrics accumulate the values over epochs and then
# print the overall result-
train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name = 'train_loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name = 'train_accuracy')

test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name = 'test_loss')
test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name = 'train_accuracy')

@tf.function
def train_one_step(model, optimizer, x, y):
    '''
    Function to compute one step of gradient descent optimization
    '''
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # Make predictions using defined model-
        y_pred = model(x)

        # Compute loss-
        loss = loss_fn(y, y_pred)

    # Compute gradients wrt defined loss and weights and biases-
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

    # type(grads)
    # list

    # Apply computed gradients to model's weights and biases-
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

    # Compute accuracy-
    train_loss(loss)
    train_accuracy(y, y_pred)

    return None


@tf.function
def test_step(model, optimizer, data, labels):
    """
    Function to test model performance
    on testing dataset
    """

    predictions = model(data)
    t_loss = loss_fn(labels, predictions)

    test_loss(t_loss)
    test_accuracy(labels, predictions)

    return None


# Initialize an instance of defined neural network model-
model = nn_model()

# User input for manual implementation of Early Stopping-
minimum_delta = 0.001
patience = 3
best_val_loss = 1
loc_patience = 0


# Train model ONCE:
for epoch in range(num_epochs):

    if loc_patience >= patience:
        print("\n'EarlyStopping' called!\n")
        break

    # Reset the metrics at the start of the next epoch
    train_loss.reset_states()
    train_accuracy.reset_states()
    test_loss.reset_states()
    test_accuracy.reset_states()

    # Dictionary to hold scalar metrics-
    history = {}

    history['accuracy'] = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    history['val_accuracy'] = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    history['loss'] = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    history['val_loss'] = np.zeros(num_epochs)

    for x, y in train_dataset:
        # train_step(x, y)
        train_one_step(model, optimizer, x, y)

    for x_t, y_t in test_dataset:
        # test_step(x_t, y_t)
        test_step(model, optimizer, x_t, y_t)

    template = 'Epoch {0}, Loss: {1:.4f}, Accuracy: {2:.4f}, Test Loss: {3:.4f}, Test Accuracy: {4:4f}'

    history['accuracy'][epoch] = train_accuracy.result()
    history['loss'][epoch] = train_loss.result()
    history['val_loss'][epoch] = test_loss.result()
    history['val_accuracy'][epoch] = test_accuracy.result()

    print(template.format(epoch + 1, 
                              train_loss.result(), train_accuracy.result()*100,
                              test_loss.result(), test_accuracy.result()*100))


    # Code for manual Early Stopping:
    if np.abs(test_loss.result() < best_val_loss) >= minimum_delta:
        # update 'best_val_loss' variable to lowest loss encountered so far-
        best_val_loss = test_loss.result()

        # reset 'loc_patience' variable-
        loc_patience = 0

    else:  # there is no improvement in monitored metric 'val_loss'
        loc_patience += 1  # number of epochs without any improvement


    # Resize numpy arrays according to the epoch when 'EarlyStopping' was called-
    for metrics in history.keys():
        history[metrics] = np.resize(history[metrics], new_shape=epoch)
```

Now, if I try to train the model multiple times instead of once, I use the following code:

```
# Instantiate a new model-
model_new = nn_model()

# Choose an optimizer and loss function for training-
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001)

# Ask user for number of times to train model-
num_training_rounds = int(input("\nEnter number of times to train model: "))


for x in range(num_training_rounds):
    print("\n\n\nTraining round number = {0}\n".format(x + 1))

    # Use new values for each iteration-
    best_val_loss = 1
    loc_patience = 0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        if loc_patience >= patience:
            print("\n'EarlyStopping' called!\n")
            break

        # Reset the metrics at the start of the next epoch
        train_loss.reset_states()
        train_accuracy.reset_states()
        test_loss.reset_states()
        test_accuracy.reset_states()

        # Dictionary to hold scalar metrics-
        history = {}

        history['accuracy'] = np.zeros(num_epochs)
        history['val_accuracy'] = np.zeros(num_epochs)
        history['loss'] = np.zeros(num_epochs)
        history['val_loss'] = np.zeros(num_epochs)

        for x, y in train_dataset:
            train_one_step(model_new, optimizer, x, y)

        for x_t, y_t in test_dataset:
            test_step(model_new, optimizer, x_t, y_t)

        template = 'Epoch {0}, Loss: {1:.4f}, Accuracy: {2:.4f}, Test Loss: {3:.4f}, Test Accuracy: {4:4f}'

        history['accuracy'][epoch] = train_accuracy.result()
        history['loss'][epoch] = train_loss.result()
        history['val_loss'][epoch] = test_loss.result()
        history['val_accuracy'][epoch] = test_accuracy.result()

        print(template.format(epoch + 1, 
                              train_loss.result(), train_accuracy.result()*100,
                              test_loss.result(), test_accuracy.result()*100))


        # Code for manual Early Stopping:
        if np.abs(test_loss.result() < best_val_loss) >= minimum_delta:
            # update 'best_val_loss' variable to lowest loss encountered so far-
            best_val_loss = test_loss.result()

            # reset 'loc_patience' variable-
            loc_patience = 0

        else:  # there is no improvement in monitored metric 'val_loss'
            loc_patience += 1  # number of epochs without any improvement


        # Resize numpy arrays according to the epoch when 'EarlyStopping' was called-
        for metrics in history.keys():
            history[metrics] = np.resize(history[metrics], new_shape=epoch)
```

But, when I execute this code, I get the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        23 
>        24         for x, y in train_dataset:
>   ---> 25             train_one_step(model_new, optimizer, x, y)
>        26 
>        27         for x_t, y_t in test_dataset:
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwds)
>       455 
>       456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
>   --> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
>       458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
>       459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py
>   in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
>       485       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
>       486       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
>   --> 487       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
>       488     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
>       489       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)    1820   def **call**(self, *args,
>   **kwargs):    1821     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
>   -> 1822     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)    1823     return
>   graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint:
>   disable=protected-access    1824
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py
>   in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)    2148
>   graph_function = self._function_cache.primary.get(cache_key, None)
>   2149         if graph_function is None:
>   -> 2150           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)    2151           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] =
>   graph_function    2152         return graph_function, args, kwargs
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py
>   in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs,
>   override_flat_arg_shapes)    2039             arg_names=arg_names,
>   2040             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
>   -> 2041             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),    2042         self._function_attributes,    2043         # Tell the ConcreteFunction
>   to clean up its graph once it goes out of
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py
>   in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature,
>   func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies,
>   arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value,
>   override_flat_arg_shapes)
>       913                                           converted_func)
>       914 
>   --> 915       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
>       916 
>       917       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py
>   in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
>       356         # **wrapped** allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
>       357         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
>   --> 358         return weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
>       359     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
>       360
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py
>   in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>       903           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
>       904             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
>   --> 905               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
>       906             else:
>       907               raise
>
> ValueError: in converted code:
>
> ```
> <ipython-input-28-0f4e8ff55201>:21 train_one_step  *
>     optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
> /home/majumdar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:433
> ```
>
> apply_gradients
>           _ = self.iterations
>       /home/majumdar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:541
>   **getattribute**
>           return super(OptimizerV2, self).**getattribute**(name)
>       /home/majumdar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:655
>   iterations
>           aggregation=tf_variables.VariableAggregation.ONLY_FIRST_REPLICA)
>       /home/majumdar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:805
>   add_weight
>           aggregation=aggregation)
>       /home/majumdar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py:744 _add_variable_with_custom_getter
>           **kwargs_for_getter)
>       /home/majumdar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py:139
>   make_variable
>           shape=variable_shape if variable_shape else None)
>       /home/majumdar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py:258
>   **call**
>           return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
>       /home/majumdar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py:219
>   _variable_v1_call
>           shape=shape)
>       /home/majumdar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/variables.py:65
>   getter
>           return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
>       /home/majumdar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py:413
>   invalid_creator_scope
>           "tf.function-decorated function tried to create "
>
> ```
> ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
> ```

What's going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I encountered a similar problem. What it appears to boil down to is that `tf.function`s are not allowed to have *any* local variables. It might be OK to update the parameter(s), ala `x = x + 1`, but that's all.

Comment: @BenSchreiber I couldn't solve this error. However, the way around this is by rerunning the train_one_step() and test_step() at the start of each training which is terminated using early stopping criterion. In this way, it works.